# How to enable a webhook for all intents?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to send all messages to my backend from the DialogFlow ES agent, but all I could find is to enable the webhook for a specefic intent.
I tried to delete all intents except the `intent.unknown` and I enabled the webhook for it but still when I test it replies with an empty message.

Answer (score 0):

For each intent, you'll need to turn on the webhook setting. All intents with the setting turned on will connect to the webhook, and you can add code that works regardless of the intent.